# Compling SCSS using @sass inside batch loop kills batch file

Tags: batch-file

I've got a batch file which compiles a list of scss files using a `FOR %%G IN () DO ()` loop.
The loop works fine **but the batch file does not resume after the loop completes** so the final "complete" message never gets run.  Any idea why?

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

FOR %%G IN (
styles/theme
styles/marketing
styles/tech
) DO @(
    @echo Compiling %%G...
    @sass --style expanded   www/%%G.scss:www/%%G.css
    @sass --style compressed www/%%G.scss:www/%%G.min.css
)
echo complete
```

NOTE: @sass is the "Compile Sass to CSS" compiler.

Comment: The _entire_ loop runs fine and you have evidence of `sass` running six times?

Comment: Correct.  The loop runs 3 times (3 input fields) with 3 echos of "Compling xxx..." and 6 @sass compiles.  I've been using this script for 1-2 years not but only now am I wanting to append the batch with more processing.

Comment: There's nothing at all in your snippet that would prevent the final `echo` from being displayed.

Comment: Thanks.  If I remove both @sass commands, final`echo` kicks in so something related to node or @sass itself is breaking the script - but only after it has run the full loop!

Comment: If you change the order of the set and put `styles/tech` first, does it still run all six times?

Comment: Same result.  @sass runs six times and echo runs 3 times. (sass,sass,echo, sass,sass,echo, sass,sass,echo) but still no final echo.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248974/discussion-between-chris-walsh-and-somethingdark).